# How to turn my old Netgear router into an access point wired to the new ASUS router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

ASUS RT-66u b1 is replacing Netgear WNDR3400v2 as my router.  I want to use the Netgear as an access point  connected via ethernet cable to the new router.  So it would look like this:
modem--->ASUS---> ethernet--->Netgear.  I want to be able to connect wirelessly to both ASUS and Netgear as needed with laptops, smartphones, Roku, Chromecast, etc.  I know that the Netgear must be set up in AP mode, but the specific features inside the router such as DHCP, Subnet, go over my head.  I have spent a lot of time inside both routers, and got a connection on the Netgear network, but then could  never login to it again.  I attached the ethernet cable between routers to the LAN ports of each.  I probably need a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Set it up this way (a way I use myself and at clients).

1. Reset your old router to factory specs so that you can start fresh.
2. Log into the old router, likely on 192.168.1.1 but check your documentation.
3. Connect an Ethernet cable from LAN port on the new router to a LAN port on the old router.
4. Determine the DHCP range of the new Router and then set the LAN address to a static IP address on the new Router. This prevents the old route from getting lost in a power outage or like.
5. On the old Router, turn DHCP OFF.
6. Restart (not reset) the old Router and you should be able to connect an Ethernet Device to the old Router and you should have DHCP from the new Router AND Internet.

Now set up Wi-Fi on the old Router as you wish.

Good luck - this works in my setup.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response.  I did 1,2,3, but not 4, because I did not know what to use for IP Subnet mask, and Gateway IP address.  I did 5.  Don't remember if  I did 6.  If you  can clear up #4 for me, I will try it.

Comment: Connect an Ethernet device to the new router and log into it. (likely a 192.168.1.1 address if you left the default .1 subnet). Look at the LAN section of the Menu when you logged in.There you will see DHCP and the range it has (often .100 to .146). Choose an IP at the low end of the range. Static IP for the old router will be the address you choose, Subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 ( for the whole subnet), Gateway is the main new router internal IP address  (eg. 192.168.1.1) . That should be enough as DNS comes from the new router

Comment: Thank you.  I will try it tonight.

Comment: Didn't work.  As before, I get internet at the AP, I can connect to its network, but I cannot then login to it again.  I have tried using Netgear's login http://routerlogin.net, but am told I am not connected to the network.  I have tried entering what I think is the static ip that I just assigned to it, no luck.  When I reset to factory settings, I can then login, to restart the process all over again.

Comment: Please keep us posted after resetting the Netgear - that was in my answer above. A nice clean reset and begin the process again is often helpful.

Comment: I have reset it 3 or 4 times already.  Anyway, I just came across this old thread in the Netgear community that sound exactly like my problem(different main router, different router/AP).  Would you review response 8 of 17, and tell me if it sounds right to you?  Here's the link:  https://community.netgear.com/t5/General-WiFi-Routers-Non/Can-t-log-into-router-configured-as-access-point/td-p/506066

Comment: I read through the entire thread twice. It does not all apply to your situation item by item. Response 8 was pretty good. (1) Make sure you know the DHCP range of your main router and know (write it down) what static IP you will use. (2) once again, connect a computer via Ethernet to the old router and reset the old router to defaults. (3) Make sure this router is working, and access Internet with it. Upgrade the firmware in the old router (an old step in the community link above). (4) Assuming all the above = yes, give the old router the static IP address on the new router. Restart all.

Comment: I will try again.  Thank you for  your time and attention.